# Show that the set $A = \{x_b,b \in K(0,1)\}$ is totally bounded in the space X.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $K(0,1)$ denote the closed unit ball in the space $X = C[0,1]$. For any $b \in K(0,1)$ let $ x_b(t) = \int_{0}^{t}b(s)ds$. Show that the set $A = \{x_b,b \in K(0,1)\}$ is totally bounded in the space X.

There are many ways to show a set is totally bounded. Should I start by proving  it is compact then conclude it is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Arzela -Ascoli Theorem. Since $|x_b (t)-x_b (s)|\leq|t-s|$ the family $\{x_b:b \in K(0,1)\}$ is equi-continuous and uniformly bounded, hence relatively compact.