# Show that the set $A:= \{x_b, b\in K(0,1) \}$ is totally bounded in the space X.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K(0,1)$ denote the closed unit bal in the space $X=C[0,1]$, with the supremum metric. For any $b \in K(0,1)$ let $x_b(t)=\int_{0}^{1} b(s)ds$. Show that the set $A:= \{x_b, b\in K(0,1) \}$ is totally bounded in the space X.

I know that there is a solution in the following link: [Show that the set $A = \{x_b,b \in K(0,1)\}$ is totally bounded in the space X.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551710/show-that-the-set-a-x-b-b-in-k0-1-is-totally-bounded-in-the-space-x)

However, I do not know the theorem mentioned in the answer to that post. Therefore, I wanted to open another post for a more "primitive" solution, I mean without using some advanced technics. First of all, since b is uniformly continuous, can I directly conclude that $x_b$ is also continuous so it is in the space. Moreover, How can I show that it is totally bounded. Should I try to prove that it is sequentially compact or should I try to construct the $\epsilon$-nets?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the idea behind Arzelà Ascoli.

Note that $\|b\| \le 1$ so all elements of $A$ are Lipschitz with rank one. Furthermore, if
$x_b \in A$ then $x_b(0) = 0$. As as consequence, $|x_b(t)| \le 1$ for all $t$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and choose $n$ such that ${1 \over n } < \epsilon$, and let $T = \{ {k \over n} \}_{k=0}^n$ and let $X = \{ {k \over n} \}_{k=-n}^n$.

Let $N$ be the collection of functions $f$ such that $f(t) \in X$ for $t \in T$ and are
joined by 
'straight lines' (affine) for $t \notin T$. It is clear that $N$ is finite.

Now choose $a\in A$. Now select a function $n \in N$ such that $|a(t)-n(t)| < \epsilon$
for all $t \in T$. Now show that $|a(t)-n(t)| < 2\epsilon$
for all $t \in [0,1]$. (The latter bound can be tightened, but this is not
necessary here.)